# Get Value From Dropzone Javascript

Tags: codeigniter, dropzone.js

i am having problem on this script, i use dropzone and codeigniter.

how to add a custom input may be hidden input then send as post to the controller

this is the html script

```
<input type="hidden" name="idnya" value="<?php echo $idnya; ?>">
<div class="dropzone">
<div class="dz-message">
<h3> Click Here</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

this is javascript dropzone

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var foto_upload= new Dropzone(".dropzone",{
url: "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/uploads_image') ?>",
maxFilesize: 2,
method:"post",
acceptedFiles:"image/*",
paramName:"userfile",
dictInvalidFileType:"Type file ini tidak dizinkan",
addRemoveLinks:true,
});
foto_upload.on("sending",function(a,b,c){
    a.token=Math.random();
    c.append("token_foto",a.token); //Menmpersiapkan token untuk masing masing foto
});
```

Comment: Maybe adding `token` to `a` (which is the `file` being uploaded) is blowing it up? Try something like: `var d = Math.random(); c.append('token_foto', d);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `codeigniter`, but as far as I know, you can use the `sending` option of `dropzone.js` to send custom data like tokens:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var foto_upload= new Dropzone(".dropzone",{
 url: "<?php echo base_url('dashboard/uploads_image') ?>",
 maxFilesize: 2,
 method:"post",
 acceptedFiles:"image/*",
 paramName:"userfile",
 dictInvalidFileType:"Type file ini tidak dizinkan",
 addRemoveLinks:true,
 sending: function (file, xhr, formData) {
        a.token=Math.random();
        formData.append('token_foto', a.token);
    }
});
```

Isn't this working for you?